# Сервер c# на сокетах http

Tags: c#, winforms, http, сокет

Лабораторная, в которой нужно сделать сервер который отвечает html файлом пользователю. Нужно использовать сокеты. Не использовать Httpresponse и т.д 
Код я сделал, на консоли он работает. А вот виндовс форм почему то начинает глючить и зависает на 10 секунд при открытии сайта.

Код работает так - принимается ответ от клиента, определяется на какой сайт он заходит (127.0.0.1:8888 или например 127.0.0.1:8888/newindex.html) и потом отправляется html файл пользователю. При этом в текстбокс виндовс форм отправляется запрос http клиента.

Проблема именно в залагивании на 10 секунд виндовс форм, работает все кроме этого нормально. 
Код:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Newweb
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public async Task Listen(string path)
        {


            int port = 8888;
            IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
            //string responsestring = File.ReadAllText(path);
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            //var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP / 1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text / html\nContent-Length: " + responsestring.Length + "\nConnection: close" + "\n\n" + responsestring);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            int bytes = 0;
            string allmessage;

            var receive = new byte[3000];

            try
            {
                socket.Bind(ipPoint);
                socket.Listen(10);

                while (true)
                {
                    allmessage = null;
                    builder.Clear();
                    Socket response = await socket.AcceptAsync();

                    //response.SendTimeout = 400;
                    bytes = response.Receive(receive);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receive, 0, bytes));
                    if (builder.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        allmessage = builder.ToString();
                        string message = NameFile(builder.ToString());


                        if (message == "\\ ")
                            message = "\\index.html";
                        path = "C:\\cfg" + message;

                        if (File.Exists(path))
                        {
                            string responsestring = File.ReadAllText(path);
                            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP / 1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text / html\nContent-Length: " + responsestring.Length + "\nConnection: close" + "\n\n" + responsestring);
                            response.Send(buffer);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string responsestring = "Not found";
                            response.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP / 1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text / html\nContent-Length: " + responsestring.Length + "\nConnection: close" + "\n\n" + responsestring));

                        }

                       //response.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        response.Close();
                        richTextBox2.Text = "";
                        richTextBox2.Invoke((Action)delegate { richTextBox2.Text = "Путь к файлу который сейчас открыт - " + path + "\n" + allmessage; });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        static string NameFile(string message)
        {
            string[] messages = message.Split('\n');
            message = messages[0];
            message = message.Replace("GET ", "");
            message = message.Replace("HTTP/1.1", "");
            message = message.Replace("/", "\\");
            message = message.Replace("\r", "");
            if (message == "\\favicon.ico")
                return null;
            return message;
        }


        private async void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string text = "C:\\cfg\\index.html";
            Listen(text);

            button2.Enabled = false;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: При этом если сделать resporse.ReceiveTimeout = 400 то при первом открытии сайта ничего не залагивает, но при втором открытии вообще никакие сайты не открываются

Comment: так может сервер в отдельном потоке запускать?

Comment: Нужен однопоточный сервер

Comment: Сервер на WinForms? Занятно...

Comment: WinForms тут только для вывода информации о запросах пользователя

Comment: WinForms тут только для _залагивания_ (в вашей терминологии).

Comment: Для чего у вас в коде пустые методы? Они имеют какое-то значение, что вы их здесь привели? Уберите их и из вопроса, и из своего кода вообще.

Comment: так и запускайте сервер в одном потоке - но не в том же, где UI

Comment: `richTextBox2.Invoke` - вот же заготовка для использования многопоточности. Так что не надо про _однопоточный сервер_.

Comment: Изначально цель была сделать именно однопоточный сервер но т.к я с этой проблемой никак не могу справится мне посоветовали сделать invoke, в любом случае это никак не помогло

Comment: Сервер - это то, что работает автоматически, без постоянного надзора за ним, без прямого участия человека. Информацию о своей работе сервер, конечно, куда то должен выводить. Обычно это делается в лог (журнал). Потом админ открывает этот лог какой-нибудь утилитой и смотрит, что там. Понимаете: сервер работает в _одном_ потоке, утилита для просмотра логов - в _другом_. GUI (в данном случае WinForms) в данном случае можно рассматривать как средство для наблюдения за сервером. То есть сервер в одном потоке, GUI - в другом. Так что запускайте поток.

Comment: Так, а разве async который используется в listen это не асихронный метод? Как он тормозит winform

Comment: Поток не обязан быть в явном виде. У вас в коде наличествуют асинхронные методы. Вот на аснихронности всё может быть сделано.

Comment: А Вы не можете подсказать что нужно изменить в коде? Что бы работало нормально

Comment: Ну так у вас не все длительные операции сделаны асинхронными. Например, чтение из файла. Или синхронный метод `Send` (хотя есть асинхронная версия). И уберите, наконец, пустые методы.

Comment: Неужели чтение маленького файла может создать глюки в форме на 10 секунд? Сейчас попробую исправить

Comment: Цикл `while (true)` - вот источник лагов.

Comment: А как сделать бесконечную проверку socket Accept без цикла?

Answer (score 0):

Метод Listen был помещен в отдельный поток, а виндовс форм был в другом потоке, проблема была решена

```
class Server
{
    string pathFile;
    Form1 form;
    RichTextBox rich;
    RichTextBox rich2;

    public Server(Form1 form1, RichTextBox rich,string str, RichTextBox rich2)
    {
        form = form1;
        this.rich = rich; 
        pathFile = str;
        this.rich2 = rich2;
    }

    public void Listen()
    {


        int port = 88;
        IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

        Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        string UserMessage, ServerMessage;

        socket.Bind(ipPoint);
        socket.Listen(0);

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                builder.Clear();
                Socket response = socket.Accept();

                byte[] receive = new byte[1024];
                var bytes = response.Receive(receive);
                builder.Append(Encoding.Default.GetString(receive, 0, bytes));
                UserMessage = builder.ToString();
                Array.Clear(receive, 0, receive.Length);

                if (builder.ToString() != "")
                {
                    string message = NameFile(builder.ToString());


                    if (message == "\\ ")
                        message = "\\index.html";


                     string path = pathFile + message;



                    if (File.Exists(path))
                    {
                       string  responsestring = File.ReadAllText(path);
                       ServerMessage = "HTTP / 1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text / html\nContent-Length: " + responsestring.Length + "\nConnection: close" + "\n\n" + responsestring;
                        response.Send(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ServerMessage));


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ServerMessage = "404 not found";
                       string responsestring = "Not found";
                       response.Send(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("HTTP / 1.1 404 Not Found\nContent-Type: text / html\nContent-Length: " + responsestring.Length + "\nConnection: close" + "\n\n" + responsestring));

                    }

                    response.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    response.Close();

                        rich.Text = "Путь к файлу который сейчас открыт - " + path + "\n" + UserMessage;
                        rich2.Text = ServerMessage;

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show((ex).ToString());
            Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();

        }
        finally{
            Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
        }
    }



    static string NameFile(string message)
    {
        string[] messages = message.Split('\n');
        message = messages[0];
        message = message.Replace("GET ", "");
        message = message.Replace("HTTP/1.1", "");
        message = message.Replace("/", "\\");
        message = message.Replace("\r", "");
        if (message == "\\favicon.ico")
            return null;
        return message;
    }
}
```